# What's meaning the of a pair of parentheses after a string literal?

Tags: bash, shell

I accidentally input the the following command into the Bash terminal:

```
exit()
```

And the Bash keeps read the next line until I input a string literal and Bash gives the error of "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token".

So I test some other similar inputs like:

```
foobar ()
```

The Bash gives the similar output. The following is the result I got:

```
~ $ foo ()
> bar
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `bar'
```

Can someone explain why. I only know the parentheses are used to create arrays or subshell. I don't know what this one actually does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the syntax for defining a shell function.  See the [Shell Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) section of the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).  It begins:

> Shell functions are a way to group commands for later execution using a single name for the group. They are executed just like a "regular" command. When the name of a shell function is used as a simple command name, the list of commands associated with that function name is executed. Shell functions are executed in the current shell context; no new process is created to interpret them.
>
> Functions are declared using this syntax:
>
> ```
> name () compound-command [ redirections ]
> ```

It's expecting you to type a compound command.  For example:

```
$ foo()
> {
> echo 'you said foo'
> }
$ foo
you said foo
```

Comment: Thanks! I just forgot about functions. It seems so weird to write only a single function header without blocks in the command line instead of in the script. I was totally confused at first.